# Reduce splash screen and white screen total time in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

How can i reduce the white screen time because when i try “

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
```

total splash screen is take 8 to 9 second, it display 1 second for splash screen and 7 to 8 second extra (i mean white screen but background same as splash screen). i required to set total time 4-5 second for starting my app.
please help me…!

Answer (score 2):

Run your app using this command to optimize speed,
**ionic cordova run android --prod**
Also, generate the pages with lazy loading. So, the pages will load only when it requires and not all at startup.